# Installing navigation stack on ROS Melodic

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been trying to use some features from the `ros-planning/navigation` stack, but it seems that it is not currently available for ROS Melodic. In my case, I need to use the `map_server` feature, in one of my applications. So far I've read that (sic) [It has been released, but a sync has not yet happened.](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/749), but all the package is available on their [github page](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation). Is there a way to manually install the downloaded package from GitHub on ROS Melodic Distro? I've already tried `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-navigation` and had no success.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300855/installing-navigation-stack-on-ros-melodic/) by [woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36979/woz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-08-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-08-17**:
have you tried building github package?

**Comment by [woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36979/woz/) on 2018-08-17**:
Haven't found any instructions on how to do that. Would you mind explaining how to?

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-08-17**:
clone into your workspace and do catkin build

**Comment by [woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36979/woz/) on 2018-08-17**:
Didn't work. Copied the whole content into my catkin_ws folder, sourced it, tried to run `catkin build` and got `catkin: command not found`. Tried `catkin_make`and nothing happened as well.

**Comment by [woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36979/woz/) on 2018-08-17**:
Also, downloaded the `catkin_tools` in order to use `catkin build` but when I tried to do it on my ws, I've got:  `The build space at '/home/<user>/catkin_ws/build' was previously built by 'catkin_make'. Please remove the build space or pick a different build space.`

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-08-17**:
catkin clean -y && catkin build

**Comment by [woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36979/woz/) on 2018-08-17**:
Didn't work as well: `[clean] Error: The current or desired workspace could not be determined. Please run` catkin clean`from within a catkin workspace or specify the workspace explicitly with the`--workspace `option.`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-17**:
That is not at all how you would build a pkg from sources.

See #q252478 for the general procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the packages are really released, built and just waiting for a sync, you can install them from the staging repository.

See [wiki/ShadowRepository](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository) for information on how to do that.

Don't build things from source if you don't have to.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36979/woz/) on 2018-08-17**:
Your last comment on my post, and this post did exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot, @gvdhoorn! Worked like a charm :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-17**:
If you're using the `shadow-fixed` repository then I'm not sure why you'd still need to build from source.

**Comment by [woz](https://answers.ros.org/users/36979/woz/) on 2018-08-17**:
I wasn't using it. To be honest, I had no idea about its existence. Anyway, both your posts helped me a lot and for that I'm really grateful :)